# Quadratic problem with two vectors linked by one quadratic constraint

Tags: nonlinear-optimization, quadratic-programming

I would like to find

$$\min_{w,b} w_iA_{ij}w_{j} + b_iB_{ij}b_j + 2\alpha_iw_i + 2\beta_ib_i $$

Constrained to:
$$ 
w_i > 0
$$

$$ 
\sum w_i = 1
$$
$$
b_i=w_i^2
$$

Where $A$ and $B$ are positive semidefinite and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are arbitrary real vectors

What is the "standard form" for this problem? What is the relevant literature?
Are there software packages than readily implement a solution?

The problem would be easy enough if it wasn't for the last constraint.